# Content Type name not translated

Tags: 7, nodes, i18n-l10n

I created a custom Drupal 7 module that creates a custom content type. It looks like this:

```
$type = node_type_set_defaults(
array(
    'type' => 'featured',
    'name' => t('Featured'),
    'description' => t('The description of the featured item.'),
    'base' => 'node_content',
    'locked' => 0,
    'custom' => 1,
    'modified' => 1
)
);

node_type_save($type);
```

I have a nl.po translation file that contains the following entries:

```
msgid "Featured"
msgstr "In de kijker"

msgid "The description of the featured item."
msgstr "De beschrijving van het in de kijker item."
```

The description gets translated as I expect when switching between languages. The content type name does not get translated at all, only English is shown.

Any ways to fix this?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: I have the same problem :(

Answer (score -1):

I hope this like help you

[How to Translate Content type name using i18n module?](https://drupal.stackexchange.com/questions/30715/how-to-translate-content-type-name-using-i18n-module)