# How do I get the translated node type of a node?

Tags: nodes, i18n-l10n

I am trying to use the node type name in `page.tpl.php` for certain content types.
Actually, we have modified the `article` type and renamed it as `News`. It's name is `News` in all languages but in Spanish, where it is `Noticias`.

The translations are defined under `Structure>Content Type>Article`.

I tried to use this code :

```
if(!empty($node) && $node->type == 'article'):
  print node_type_get_name($node);
endif;
```

but the node type is always printed as `News`, even on Spanish pages.

I tried wrapping this in a `t()` , but no change.
Am I doing something wrong here ? 
Thanks for your help !

Comment: possible duplicate of [How to Translate Content type name using i18n module?](http://drupal.stackexchange.com/questions/30715/how-to-translate-content-type-name-using-i18n-module)

Comment: I have all internationalization modules installed and activated, so I think this question is not the same as mine. [Screenshot1](http://i.imgur.com/ViGqaXt.png) [Screenshot2](http://i.imgur.com/HqkeX6S.png)

Comment: Actually, I might have the problem described in this question, but the given answer only allows one to start over its drupal installation. Our site is a production site, so that is not an option.

Answer (score -1):

I have edited html.tpl.php

I have added this code before starting the body tag in order to replace body css classes with translated

```
<?php
    $body_classes_array = explode(' ',$classes);
    foreach($body_classes_array as $key=>$class)
    {
        $body_classes_array[$key] = t($class);
    }
    $classes = implode(' ',$body_classes_array);
?>
```

after this modification, you can search css class name in translate page and put a suitable translation for it.

so final html.tpl.php is

```
<?php

/**
 * @file
 * Default theme implementation to display the basic html structure of a single
 * Drupal page.
 *
 * Variables:
 * - $css: An array of CSS files for the current page.
 * - $language: (object) The language the site is being displayed in.
 *   $language->language contains its textual representation.
 *   $language->dir contains the language direction. It will either be 'ltr' or 'rtl'.
 * - $rdf_namespaces: All the RDF namespace prefixes used in the HTML document.
 * - $grddl_profile: A GRDDL profile allowing agents to extract the RDF data.
 * - $head_title: A modified version of the page title, for use in the TITLE
 *   tag.
 * - $head_title_array: (array) An associative array containing the string parts
 *   that were used to generate the $head_title variable, already prepared to be
 *   output as TITLE tag. The key/value pairs may contain one or more of the
 *   following, depending on conditions:
 *   - title: The title of the current page, if any.
 *   - name: The name of the site.
 *   - slogan: The slogan of the site, if any, and if there is no title.
 * - $head: Markup for the HEAD section (including meta tags, keyword tags, and
 *   so on).
 * - $styles: Style tags necessary to import all CSS files for the page.
 * - $scripts: Script tags necessary to load the JavaScript files and settings
 *   for the page.
 * - $page_top: Initial markup from any modules that have altered the
 *   page. This variable should always be output first, before all other dynamic
 *   content.
 * - $page: The rendered page content.
 * - $page_bottom: Final closing markup from any modules that have altered the
 *   page. This variable should always be output last, after all other dynamic
 *   content.
 * - $classes String of classes that can be used to style contextually through
 *   CSS.
 *
 * @see template_preprocess()
 * @see template_preprocess_html()
 * @see template_process()
 *
 * @ingroup themeable
 */
?><!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML+RDFa 1.0//EN"
  "http://www.w3.org/MarkUp/DTD/xhtml-rdfa-1.dtd">
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml" xml:lang="<?php print $language->language; ?>" version="XHTML+RDFa 1.0" dir="<?php print $language->dir; ?>"<?php print $rdf_namespaces; ?>>

<head profile="<?php print $grddl_profile; ?>">
  <?php print $head; ?>
  <title><?php print $head_title; ?></title>
  <?php print $styles; ?>
  <?php print $scripts; ?>
</head>
<?php
    $body_classes_array = explode(' ',$classes);
    foreach($body_classes_array as $key=>$class)
    {
        $body_classes_array[$key] = t($class);
    }
    $classes = implode(' ',$body_classes_array);
?>
<body class="<?php print $classes; ?>" <?php print $attributes;?>>
  <div id="skip-link">
    <a href="#main-content" class="element-invisible element-focusable"><?php print t('Skip to main content'); ?></a>
  </div>
  <?php print $page_top; ?>
  <?php print $page; ?>
  <?php print $page_bottom; ?>
</body>
</html>
```

I hope my post can help you.

Comment: I don't see how translating class name can be relevant in my case ? My problem is that node_get_type_name is not translated, even when wrapped in a t() function.